# How to use Gradle to build a JAR that depends on another JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Eclipse workspace with a declared workset configured to have several projects. Some are to generate JAR files and others are web applications that use those JAR files. In my architecture I have a JAR that will consist of domain core services and another one that depends on the first one that will consist of higher level services. Finally I will have some web applications that use those both JARs.

The first JAR project is build with Gradle, based on the following script

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral();
}

jar {
    baseName = 'br.ufpr.unidades.dominio'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.7.Final'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

As anyone can see, it´s a very simple `build.gradle` file and the build works fine with it. The expected JAR file is generated in the expected destination folder.

Now, here comes the build script for the second JAR:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'br.ufpr.unidades.dominio.hibernate'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    runtime fileTree(dir: '../dominio/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.7.Final'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

The second file is very similar to the first one, except it has a dependency on generated JAR:

```
    runtime fileTree(dir: '../dominio/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
```

Eclipse doesn´t show any problems, but when I try to build the second JAR project I get many Class not found error messages, like the one below:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      build
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:compileJava
D:\Users\alex\Documents\Eclipse\workspace\unidades\dominio.hibernate\src\main\java\dominio\hibernate\HibernateCargoRepository.java:7: error: package unidades.dominio does not exist
import unidades.dominio.Cargo;
```

The message is clear: I´m importing a package that is not being found during the build, so the classes such a package has cannot be referenced in my code. Such a package is declared in the first and perfectly generated JAR file. It also is visible under `Referenced Libraries` item in the Eclipse project, so Gradle was able to find it to reference it in design time, but not to build the second JAR.

After all that, I suspect it´s a dependency management problem, but I can´t see which it is and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are You using classes from the jar under `dominio/build/libs` in the second project? If so, this should be a `compile` dependency. I'd also recommend setting a multimodule gradle project.

Comment: @Opal: well, that´s the good thing on talking to experts! Thank you so much, your suggestion just fixed the problem! Please, add it as an answer and I will mark it as solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are You using classes from the jar under `dominio/build/libs` in the second project? If so, this should be a `compile` dependency. I'd also recommend setting a `multimodule` gradle project. [Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) are the docs.